# Can we use multiple application for Mod_auth_openidc, such that we can use different client ids in one apache

Tags: apache, authentication, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc, mod-auth

I am working on Mod_auth_openidc with okta integration, where we need to provide OIDCClientID, OIDCClientSecret in the apache configurations that is linked with OIDC app from okta but i want to use multiple application,  i.e multiple client ids.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable if you put each site needing its own OIDCClientID and OIDCClientSecret in its own virtual host. I am currently able to manage logins to 6 different relying parties with a single originating party.